# scikit-learn cross_validate: reveal test set indices

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

In [`sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) , is there a way to output the samples / indices which were used as test set by the CV splitter for each fold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option to specify the cross-validation generator, using `cv` option :

> cv int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, default=None
> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs
> for cv are:
>
> None, to use the default 5-fold cross validation,
>
> int, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified)KFold,
>
> CV splitter,
>
> An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.
>
> For int/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either
> binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other cases,
> KFold is used. These splitters are instantiated with shuffle=False so
> the splits will be the same across calls.

If you provide it as an input to `cross_validate` :

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()

kf = KFold(5, random_state = 99, shuffle = True)
cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=kf)
```

You can extract the index like this:

```
idx = [test_index for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X)]
```

Where the first in the list will be the test index for the 1st fold and so on..

Comment: If there is no direct way to tell `cross_validate` to save the test set indices, I think this is the approach we are left with (i.e. re-running the splitting after the actual CV, to obtain the splits). However, there is a slight problem in the code: using random_state without shuffle won't work.

Comment: ...added the shuffle argument